# Работа с двоичными данными

Tags: массивы, pascal

Как можно записать двумерный массив двоичных данных в Pascal?

Comment: Ответ - как угодно. Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Неужели такой ответ вам подходит? Давайте может все же уточним вопрос и найдем лучшее решение? )

Comment: Было бы неплохо) Я создал в паскале массив bin: array [1..2] of byte = ((0001),(0110)); Программа распознает его элементы как 1 и 110,а мне бы хотелось,чтобы она видела именно двоичные значения. И ещё у меня вопрос по двумерным массивам,может быть создать чат?

Comment: Заходи - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44141/binary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двоичные данные можно хранить в разном виде.

Например в виде массива булевых элементов (1 элемент = 1 бит).

```
arr: array of array of Bool;
```

Можно хранить в виде обычных Integer и обращаться к ним по маскам для выделения определенных битов (1 Integer = 32 бита).

```
arr: array of array of Integer;
```

И даже в виде строки текста (1 символ = 1 бит).

```
arr: array of array of String;
```